# Angular: 'Module not found Error' when change angular version

Tags: angular, upgrade

I tried to upgrade my angular application from version 9 to version 14. I tried run:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm cache clear
delete node_modules + package-lock.json
npm install @angular/cli@14.2.12
change angular/core, angular/common .... to 14.2.12
npm i
ng update @angular/core@14.2.12 ....
```

But after that, I'm facing with this error.
[image]
Anyone have solution for this issue. Many thanks.

resolve my issue, I think because some wrong in my application config

Answer (score 0):

Moving from Angular 9 to 14 for a large code base can be a big migration. You should do it gradually, upgrading one version at a time.

Use the Angular Migrate Tool (see https://angular.io/cli/update) to go from 9 to 10, 10 to 11, until you get to 14. create a new branch, and commit your migration changes after each successful migration step.

You can migrate each angular library in lock step by using this ng update command with all of your angular libraries:
`ng update @angular/cli@^10 @angular/core@^10 @angular/common@^10`

You can see all the things that have changed from 9 to 14 by using their update guide: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=9.0-14.0